# PostgreSQL full-text fuzzy seach ordered by rank

Tags: sql, postgresql, full-text-search, fuzzy-search

I'd like to implement full-text search on `users.about` column. For this purpose I have created the following GIN index:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION make_tsvector(about TEXT)
    RETURNS tsvector AS
$$
BEGIN
    RETURN to_tsvector(about);
END
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql IMMUTABLE;

CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS idx_fts_users ON users
USING gin(make_tsvector(about));
```

How to correctly construct the SQL query in order to be able to search by `users.about` column different query terms. For example, I'd like to use by following query term provided from UI:

```
'java c# dephY php hadoop'
```

I'd like to be able to search by this term independently of word order and ideally with fuzzy search capability(as you may see I made a mistake in `dephY`. I'd like to be able to find `delhi` in this case as well.). Result must be sorted by rank. Please advise how to construct such query in PostgreSQL.

Comment: FTS doesn't itself deal with typos.  You can make something with pg_trgm (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/pgtrgm.html#id-1.11.7.40.8) to integrate with it.  Or maybe just use pg_trgm, as disjointed fragments of jargon is not what FTS is for.